# Laravel not adding stylesheets to head, adding to body

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am starting in Laravel developerment, and I am trying to include script tags and css styles in the head element, they are in the head element in my code, but when adding through laravel's methods, they add to the body.

Code:

```
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
{{ HTML::style('css/reset.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/welcome.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/script.js') }}
</head>
```

And the result is in the picture bellow:

[image]

Any ideas??

** Fix **

I realized that I was not incuding the footer part, so the tags were not being closed.

Comment: Most probably you have an error in you html file. Make sure that the tags are closed where they should be closed

Comment: did the trick! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happens when your HTML is not properly formatted. Make sure you close all your tags in the proper order and it should be fixed.